# Handle project version in VB6 /outdir

Tags: compilation, vb6

So I´m not very good at using batch-files, but I do need to use this. What I´m doing in the batchfile is following:

1 - Using `tf.exe` to get latest build from Main and updating the projectfiles.
2 - Compiling every file `(.vbp)` and then placing the exe / dlls in a folder called "Temp".

```
START VB6.exe /make "C:\Place1\Place2\development\Main\components\Place3\source\Place4\project11.vbp" /outdir C:\Temp\Place
```

This all works just fine, the "problem" I'm having with outdir, is that when I'm compiling every file, I do get correct major and minor version, but I want the folder structure, instead of it being "Temp", I´d like it in the batchfile to place it (mkdir) with the same major/minor version that is set in the project file.

So lets say I get latest project files, they are set to 1.0.0 I´d like the /outdir to be set to the same folder as version.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: It's up to you to create your build tooling -- VB6 is very primitive for large scale multi-project compilation. Mind that your ActiveX DLLs do get *registered* in your temp `/outdir` so you cannot just `rmdir` it when done or you risk leaving cruft in your registry.

Comment: You might find that Poweshell is better set up for this sort of task. I don't know enough to tell you how however.

Comment: wqw, I´m well aware of this, we do run a install.bat after the /outdir been used, and its been moved to correct folder which unregister and register the dll at correct place. But its the manual copy/paste I´d like to skip, to go from a Temp folder, to actually make a folder which uses the version number thats being showned in project properties.

Comment: CMaster, Yes powershell would probably help alot, but thats not what we´re using this time around :-(

Comment: What exactly is your problem, assigning the version to a variable, or using the variable to make the folder?

Comment: Using variable to make the folder, not sure how to get the project version thats added to be mkdir (projectfile version)

Comment: Still not sure I understand, but you said your getting the version, so now just assign it to a variable, `SET MY_FOLDER="VERSION_INFO"`. Notice the lack of spaces. Then you read it back with `MkDir %MY_FOLDER%`